# Input & Coefficients from time domain to frequency, add them together and back to time domain

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I am currently studying computer science and i have a task to solve for my lab project. I have to transfer input's signal & coefficients' from time domain to frequency domain, add them together and transfer back to time domain. My results have to match filter function output. However i cannot seem to find what am doing wrong here. I think its something wrong when i add two frequency via conj function. Unfortunately neither my teacher nor my lab supervisor are interested in actually teaching anything so i have to find answers on my own. Hope you guys can help.

```
clc
clear
B = [0.2];
A = [1,-0.5];
xt = ones(1,20);
xt = padarray(xt,[0,100])
A1 = 1;
A2 = 1;
f1 = 1;
f2 = 25;
fs = 1000;

xd = fft(xt);
wd = freqz(B,A,length(xt));
y = filter(B,A,xt);
yd = conj((wd)').*xd;

yt = real(ifft(yd));

subplot(4,2,1);
plot(xt)
title('Input signal')

subplot(4,2,2);
plot(abs(xd))
title('Input in frequency domain')

subplot(4,2,4);
plot(abs(wd))
title('Coefficients in frequency domain')

subplot(4,2,7);
plot(y)
title('Output using FILTER function')

subplot(4,2,6);
plot(yd)
title('Adding input with coefficients in frequency domain')

subplot(4,2,8);
plot(yt)
title('Back to time domain using IFFT')
```

Comment: I would change your question to something like "Filtering in the time domain does not match with frequency domain multiplication."

Comment: @BrianGoodwin That is a better title.  I didn't understand the objective of the question until I read the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matlab function `freqz()` can be a little misleading. The "FFT" domain of your coefficients needs to be generated differently. Replace your stuff with the following code, and it should give you what you want:

```
xt = xt.';
xd = fft(xt);
wd = freqz(B,A,length(xt),'whole');
y = filter(B,A,xt);
yd = wd.*xd;
yt = ifft(yd);

figure
plot(abs(xd))
hold on
plot(abs(wd))

figure
plot(y,'.k','markersize',20)
hold on
plot(yt,'k')
hold off
```

Also, a note on the `'` operator with complex vectors: unless you use the `.'` operator (e.g., `x = x.'`), it will transpose the vector while taking the complex conjugate, i.e., `(1+1i).' = (1+1i)` while `(1+1i)' = (1-1i)`

Comment: Thanks! Did not expect such a fast reply!! It really works :)

Comment: Oh. Sorry, am new :) Marked!